Is the completion of a (not necessarily Noetherian) local ring flat?
Let $R$ be a commutative local ring with unity, $\mathfrak{m}$  its maximal ideal, and $\widehat{R}$ the $\mathfrak{m}$-adic completion of $R$.
Is it true in general that the canonical morphism $R\rightarrow \widehat{R}$ is flat?
If $R$ is Noetherian, it is a well-known result that $R\rightarrow \widehat{R}$ is faithfully flat.
I am interested in the case where $R$ is $\textbf{not}$ Noetherian. If this is not true in full generality, are there any other conditions that ensure that this completion is flat?

This if false: let $R=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}$ the ring of integers of the $p$-adic completion of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}p$. Then, for $\mathfrak{m}$ the maximal ideal of that ring one has $\mathfrak{m}^2=\mathfrak{m}$, so $R\to \widehat{R}$ is the map $\mathcal{O}{\mathbb{C}p}\to \mathcal{O}{\mathbb{C}_p}/\mathfrak{m}$ which is evidently not flat.

The only results that i know in this direction are results of Gabber/Fujiwara--Varshavsky, but they certainly won't apply to your cases. For example, suppose that you have a ring $A$ and a finitely generated ideal $I\subseteq A$ such that (a) any finitely generated $A$-module $M$ has bounded $I$-torsion (i.e., $M[I^n]=M[I^m]$ for all $n,m\gg 0$), and (b) $\mathrm{Spec}(A)-V(I)$ is a Noetherian scheme. Then, the $I$-adic completion map $A\to \widehat{A}$ is flat. Of course, in the non-Noetherian situation your $\mathfrak{m}$ won't often be finitely generated, so this is not particularly useful.

Generally in many cases I deal with, the moral of the story is that its not really the $\mathfrak{m}$-adic topology you want to consider, but instead the $I$-adic topology for some finitely generated ideal $I\subseteq \mathfrak{m}$. In the example I gave above, this manifests itself by considering not the $\mathfrak{m}$-adic topology on $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}$ but the $p$-adic topology, for which it is complete.

Sorry Fujiwara--Varshavsky is the trace formula lol, I meant Fujiwara--Kato.

@AlexYoucis Thanks a lot for the very instructive example! It turns out that my interests are also towards $p$-adic stuff, so your example is crucially relevant to my interests! Thanks again! I have one final inquiry if you have time. If the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ is finitely generated (without assuming that $R$ itself is Noetherian), is it still true then that $R\rightarrow \widehat{R}$ is flat?

Unless  Gabber/Fujiwara--Kato applies, then I am not sure. Frankly, as far as I know, non-Noetherian local rings with finitely generated maximal ideal are a bit obscure.  I doubt in practice that the knowledge of such a result would be useful. I feel like you secretly have another question you are trying to understand that this would be helpful for. If so, it might make sense to edit this question to ask it or, if it's far enough away in content, a new question.

@AlexYoucis Well, you got me! Indeed, in my work, I constructed some algebra over some non-Archimedean field  $K$ and this algebra is of interest to me, and I expect it to be an affinoid $K$-algebra. I managed to show that this would follow from the flatness of the canonical mapping of the completion of the local ring. Thus the interest in the question. Now that I have thought about it, I believe that the Fujiwara-Kato Criterion that you mentioned might be verified in my case! But I need to carry out the details of course. If it does not work out, I might pose a more detailed question...

on the matter, but I believe it will be more appropriate for the math overflow. In all cases, I am grateful that you have brought this criterion to my attention, and it might be the exact technical tool that I need! So a Huge Thank you!!
For future readers who might find this criterion interesting, the criterion can be found as proposition 8.2.4 (page 173) in the book "Foundations of Rigid Geometry I" by K. Fujiwara and F. Kato.

@AlexYoucis If you do not mind, may you turn your very helpful comments, including the counter-example and the criterion, into an answer? I feel like they may be helpful to more people.  If we do not get any more general results soon, I am very keen to accept it.

No, it is not true that $R\to \widehat{R}_\mathfrak{m}$ is flat for an arbitrary local ring $(R,\mathfrak{m})$.
Example: Let
$$R=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}:=\{x\in\mathbb{C}_p:|x|\leqslant 1\},$$
where $\mathbb{C}_p$ is the $p$-adic completion of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$, and where $|\cdot|$ is the $p$-adic absolute value. Then, observe that
$$\mathfrak{m}=\{x\in\mathbb{C}_p:|x|<1\}.$$
Moreover, one has that $\mathfrak{m}^2=\mathfrak{m}$. Indeed, if $x$ is in $\mathfrak{m}$ then, as $\mathbb{C}_p$ is algebraically closed (by Krasner's lemma) there exists some $y$ in $\mathbb{C}_p$ such that $y^2=x$. But, $|y|^2=|y^2|=|x|<1$, and so $|y|<1$ and so, in fact, $y$ is in $\mathfrak{m}$. But, this is quite bad then as the natural map $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}/\mathfrak{m}^n\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}/\mathfrak{m}$ is an isomorphism for $n\geqslant 1$, and so the natural map $R\to \widehat{R}_\mathfrak{m}$ is the quotient map $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}/\mathfrak{m}$, which is evidently not flat. $\blacksquare$
Here are some cases where $I$-adic completions are flat:

if $R$ is a Noetherian ring and $I\subseteq R$ is an ideal, then $R\to\widehat{R}_I$ is flat (e.g., see Tag 00MB),

if $V$ is a valuation ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ and $a$ is a non-zero element of $\mathfrak{m}$ then, assuming $V$ is $a$-adically separated, the $a$-adic completion map $V\to \widehat{V}_a$ is faithfully flat (combine [FK, Chapter 0, Theorem 9.1.1 (2)] with [FK, Chapter 0, Proposition 6.4.5 (4)] and the fact that a $V$-algebra is flat if and only if it's torsion free),

a result of Gabber/Fujiwara--Kato says that if $A$ is a ring and $I\subseteq A$ a finitely generated ideal such that (a) any finitely generated $A$-module $M$ has bounded $I$-torsion (i.e., $M[I^n]=M[I^m]$ for all $n,m\gg 0$), and (b) $A$ is Noetherian outside of $I$ (i.e., $\mathrm{Spec}(A)−V(I)$ is a Noetherian scheme), then, the $I$-adic completion map $A\to \widehat{A}_I$ is flat.


These are all examples that useful in rigid geometry, where one has to deal with rings like $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}$ which while non-Noetherian are not so bad.
Example: Any finitely generated algebra $R$ over $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}$ satisfies the conditions of the third bullet above with respect to the ideal $pR$. Indeed, $\mathrm{Spec}(R)-V(pR)=\mathrm{Spec}(R[\tfrac{1}{p}])$ is finite type over $\mathbb{C}_p$ and so Noetherian. Moreover, as $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}$ has bounded $p$-torsion (exercise!) the same is true for $R$ (e.g., see [FK, Chapter 0, Proposition 8.2.1]). So, the $p$-adic completion map $R\to\widehat{R}$ is flat. $\blacksquare$
[FK] Fujiwara, K. and Kato, F., 2018. Foundations of rigid geometry I.
